# How to integrate Cucumber with TestNG example?

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

I am trying to use [cucumber-testng](https://github.com/lionhearth/cucumber-testng), it looks simple. So far I have installed following packages using gradle:

`compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-testng:1.2.2'` (cucumber with testng) 
`compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4'` (java now recognizes cucumber annotations) 
`cucumberRuntime 'info.cukes:cucumber-groovy:1.1.6'` (to run cucumber-testng tests)

How do I run these tests? I see errors when running this via the command `gradle cucumber`.

My test outline in java is as follows: 
*src/test/resources/features/Structured.feature*
*src/test/java/test/httpapi/structure/StructuredFeatureRunner.java*

```
package test.httpapi.structure;  

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;


@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/Structured.feature",
              glue = "test.httpapi.structure",
              format = {"pretty"})
public class StructuredFeatureRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

Comment: Can you post error details, stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above problem i was having. It was a problem with gradle plugin. I now see my failed cucumber test in stack trace.

```
Scenario: Create Structured Store schema in xyz # Structured.feature:4
Given Structured Store object logged into silk  # StructuredStoreApiTests.Structured_Store_object_logged_into_Silk()
When i use api createStructuredRepo                # StructuredStoreApiTests.i_use_api_createStructuredRepo()
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at rapture.httpapi.structure.StructuredStoreApiTests.i_use_api_createStructuredRepo(StructuredStoreApiTests.java:59)
    at ✽.When i use api createStructuredRepo(Structured.feature:6)

Then i should see schema created in xyz       # StructuredStoreApiTests.i_should_see_schema_created_in_XYZ(Boolean)

Failed scenarios:
Structured.feature:4 # Scenario: Create Structured Store schema in xyz

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
3 Steps (1 failed         , 1 skipped, 1 passed)
0m0.137s

java.lang.NullPointerException
at rapture.httpapi.structure.StructuredStoreApiTests.i_use_api_createStructuredRepo(StructuredStoreApiTests.java:59)
at ✽.When i use api createStructuredRepo(Structured.feature:6)
```

Comment: Problem is i feel, i am not passing objects in between cucumber steps. How do i do that?